# How can I left-align a caption?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I am using this for captions:

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=normal,up]{caption}
```

But they all come out centred - I want them aligned with the left margin - how can I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add the options `justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false`. This is described in the `caption` manual.

Comment: brilliant thanks... is there anyway to "pad" the top of a caption so it has a little space above it?

Comment: Again, this is in the manual. It's the `skip` option.

Comment: forgiveme, i only started on latex today, i dont even know where i'd find the manual!

Comment: If you're using TeX Live, run `texdoc caption` at the command line. Otherwise, you can just read it on the [web](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf).

Comment: This changes the format of the caption is it possible to prevent it?

Answer (score 15):

Put `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}` after `\begin{figure}` would solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Moreover, your answer is a duplicate of the one already present.

Comment: @CarLaTeX To be honest, I think, that the crucial information here is mentioning `\captionsetup` macro.

Comment: @Eenoku You're right, the original answer is even more incomplete.