# Align Caption to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

[image]

I am trying to align caption to the left but its coming centered. Please see the figure. The code is

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{Figure 1.pdf}
\caption{The caption is coming to the center. It should be aligned to the left. }
\label{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
```

The previously mentioned solutions were tried. But they didn't work.
[How can I left-align a caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/how-can-i-left-align-a-caption)

Any solution for the above problem.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 amsmath,amssymb,
]{revtex4-1}
\draft

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{times}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg, .png, .eps, .tiff}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figure 3.pdf}
\caption{}   
\label{Figure 4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: Does `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionsetup{format=hang}` work?

Comment: I am already using the \usepackage{caption}. And By additionally using \captionsetup{format=hang} does not seem to provide the solution

Comment: Please add a compilable code starting from `\documentclass{...}` and ending at `\end{document}`. Now we are really clueless as to why and what is not working for you.

Comment: See my above comment please.

Comment: Don't use `caption` package with `revtex4-1` package. It is not compatible (read the log) Then the captions are left aligned. Why you need `caption` package?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 42):

You should add the following instruction to the preamble, *after* loading the `caption` package:

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
```

If you want "hanging indentation" of multiline captions, you should add the option

```
format=hang
```

to the argument of `\captionsetup`.

A full MWE (with all packages not relevant for the issue at hand removed from the preamble):

[image]

```
\documentclass[aip,amsmath,amssymb,draft]{revtex4-1}
%%% \draft % this instruction is deprecated -- use 'draft' option instead

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
              singlelinecheck = false}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{2}  % just for this example

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figure3.pdf}
\caption{The caption is now no longer centered. Instead, it is left-aligned, which is also known as ``ragged-right''.}   
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `caption` is not recommended to be used with this class. Remove `caption` package and the captions are left aligned. Why OP loaded `caption` is not clear to me. Similarly `\draft` is obsolete over `draft` option.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Without the `caption` package, the captions will be fully justified only if they're longer than one line. Single-line captions will still be centered.

Comment: But `caption` is not compatible with `revtex4-1`, hence it will break something some where.

Comment: caption package is used for the working of \captionof in some of the figures.

Comment: @HarishKumar - I can find no warning messages in the log file related to an incompatibility between the `revtex4-1` class and the `caption` package.

Comment: [Really strange then](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N4aaZ.png)

Comment: @HarishKumar -- Really strange indeed. Could this be due to you (apparently) MikTeX 2.9 whereas I use TeXlive 2015?

Comment: @Mico: I have no clue. May be other people can check too.

Comment: @HarishKumar - My bad! The reason I wasn't getting the warning message was that I had commented out the caption-related directives! After reinstating the instructions, the warning does show up in the log file. That said, I honestly can't tell if the warning message is generated out of an overabundance of caution or because there are some real incompatibilities. For sure, the user guide of the `caption` package does not appear to mention problems with the `revtex4-1` class.

Comment: The `caption` package just detects an incompatibility caused by an unknown version of `\@makecaption`, so this is a rather dump mechanism. Is this is a minor or major issue? No-one knows unless he/she takes a closer look at the sources, to see what exactly is happening, and what features of the `revtex` document class will be overwritten by loading the `caption` package.

Comment: what if figure is not `textwidth`? This solutions aligns with textwidth it seems but not with figure.

Comment: @snoram - Instead of `width=\textwidth`, one can of course set `width=0.8\textwidth` -- or any other width fraction less than 1. (For reasons that are hopefully obvious, one shouldn't make the figure wider than `\textwidth`.) If you choose a width factor less than 1, you should probably also supply the instruction `\centering`, in order to center the image file horizontally.

Comment: How do I change the colon in "Fig. 3: " to a period?

Comment: @Rendicahya - Assuming your document loads the `caption` package, the way to to change from `Figure 3:` to `Figure 3.` is to specify the package option `labelsep=period`. If you use `\captionsetup`, just add `labelsep=period` to the list of comma-separated arguments of the `\captionsetup`.

Comment: This changes the format of the caption that is come from cls , is it possible to keep the font type and size unchanged?

Comment: @alper - The entire purpose of using the `caption` package is to modify the format of captions selectively. However, unless one specifies options to the contrary, employing the `caption` package should *not* cause a change in font shape or size employed in captions. Which document class do you employ?

Comment: @Mico I was using `\documentclass{ieeeccess}` its template (https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/LaTeX.zip) ; they use `textbf{}` and left-alignment for all table and figure captions. I just wanted to apply `textbf{}` to all figure and table captions but while keeping the original style such as `Figure` text color is blue ; note that I can as new question related to this

Comment: @alper - Thanks. Yes, please go ahead and ask a new, self-contained question.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, hope it is clear: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/667828/127048

Answer (score 2):

The `caption` package is not recommended, as it interferes with the caption formatting of `revtex`. The `boxhandler` package doesn't seem to have this drawback.

A few comments about your code: ther's a warning in the .log file to inform that the `draft` command is obsolete and should be replaced with the `draft` option for the document class. The `times` package is also obsolete, and should be replaced with `mathptmx` or, better, `newtxtext, newtxmath`, which uses `TeX Gyre Termes`, a more complete clone of `Times`.

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 amsmath,amssymb,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg, .png, .eps, .tiff}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\bxfigure{\textit{Piero di Cosimo}, The Death of Procris (1495)}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old, but I came across this after having a similar problem and found a simple solution that isn't mentioned for those who are just looking to use `\captionof` for figures (like in minipages as I was using).

The `caption` package has the wording in their docs:
And if you are just interested in using the
command `\captionof`, loading of the very small `capt-of` package is usually sufficient.

Changing `\usepackage{caption`} to
`\usepackage{capt-of}` worked for me. Because `capt-of` is small, it doesn't interfere with other revtek captioning like full line usage -the caption uses the full line on both left and right side.