# Put caption in the left of the figure a

Tags: captions, right-to-left

how can I Put title of figure in the left of the figure as in the attached capture ?[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure

Comment: This may be helpful:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275131/align-caption-to-the-left

Comment: Do note that `floatrow` is extremely buggy. So don't try anything too adventurous with it ....

Comment: using floatrow do not work for me