# Avoid automatic centering of caption

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, subcaption

I have in the LaTeX source file:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{figure}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.50\textwidth}

  \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{RegressionFixedObservedN4451.png}

  \caption{Based on the observed data sets}

  \label{fig:RegressionFixedObservedN4451}

\end{subfigure}%

\caption{Regression plot for the fixed condition of the ACT (N = 445). The
 x-axis represents the natural logarithm of the absolute value of the minimum
 residual score belonging to the sequence of 14 consecutive bars with the
 smallest MSE. The y-axis represents the smallest MSE. The top line is the
 line $y = 2x + \ln{10}$. The bottom line is the line $y = 2x-\ln{10}$. The
 line exactly in between is the line $y=2x$.}

\label{fig:observedfixedcondion}

\end{figure}
```

and the caption is centered. But I want the caption NOT centered. How should I do this?

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a complete, compileable example document, i.e. with all used packages (are you loading the `caption` package as well?). Also, which caption are you referring to: the main caption or the one in the subfigure or both?

Comment: When I compile your code none of the captions are centered. The subcaption is just indented a little (which makes it looks almost as being centered under the image, but this depends on the image width) and the main caption is *justified*. Please explain a little better what you require.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a full MWE. By the way, this question has been answered several times on stackexchange: [Align Caption to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275131/align-caption-to-the-left)

I don't know what caption you are referring to, but this should do the trick:

```
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
```

Comment: If this question was asked before, why not leave a link in the comments? And mark as duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you for the comment. I added a link but I am not able to close the topic and mark it as a duplicate,

Comment: The command \captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false} really did help. Therefore, Felix, thank you very much. But what to do if I want to have the caption 'raggedleft' as well?

Comment: @AdvanderVen glad I could help, but next time please try the search bar first :-) you can mark your question as answered as well. 

You can use captionsetup in every figure environment, where you want your caption to be adjusted.

Comment: Hi Felix, Your last sentence was of great help again. However, what I want is the spacing of words and letters within a line so that the margins of all the full lines in a column (a caption) are the same. This is now the case on the left but not on the right. How can I do this so that it is also the case on the right.

Comment: Hi Felix, I have looked for the various options for justification but I could not find the one I was looking for i.e. not ragged neither left nor right. Perhaps you can fix the source file, however, I do not know how to attach the source file to this comment.

Comment: @AdvanderVen I suggest you open a new question. Please make sure that you provide a full MWE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
You need to make sure that your code is reproducible so that we can understand your problem and fix it.