# The use of justification

Tags: justification

I used the following Latex source file:

```
\RequirePackage{lineno}   
\documentclass[aps,prl]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files   
\usepackage{epstopdf}   % this graphic package converts eps to pdf for easier usage of eps files  
\usepackage{lpic}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}   
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{listingsutf8}  
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\lstset{mathescape=true} 
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right\rangle} 
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right|} 
\newcommand{\is}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{compatibility=false}  
\begin{document}

\textbf{Corresponding author information}\\
Ad van der Ven, email: a.vanderven@pwo.ru.nl

\begin{figure}

  \begin{subfigure}{0.50\textwidth}

{\bf Figure}

  \caption{Based on the observed data sets}

  \label{fig:RegressionFixedObservedN4451}

\end{subfigure}

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\caption{Regression plot for the fixed condition of the ACT (N = 445). The
 x-axis represents the natural logarithm of the absolute value of the minimum
 residual score belonging to the sequence of 14 consecutive bars with the
 smallest MSE. The y-axis represents the smallest MSE. The top line is the
 line $y = 2x + \ln{10}$. The bottom line is the line $y = 2x-\ln{10}$. The
 line exactly in between is the line $y=2x$.}
\label{fig:observedfixedcondion}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However I do not want to have `justification=raggedright` nor `justification=raggedleft`. I simply want the caption aligned left and right. It seems justification does not have that option. I could not find an answer at 'Questions that may already have your answer'.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  To include source code in your question, highlight the code block and click the `{}` icon above the edit box.  This will indent each line of code by 4 spaces in the edit box, which has the visual effect of rendering like code in the html page.

Comment: To format inline "code" in your question, delimit the code with grave accents, like `\`code=0\``

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468942/avoid-automatic-centering-of-caption

Comment: Hi Steven B. Segletes, Thanks for repairing the layout of my question.

Comment: I wouldn't bother about formatting. Revtex folks will restyle anyway if the current output does not fit their needs.

Comment: Dear Johannes_B The related site you suggested did not answer my question. I do not know what you mean by 'Revtex folks' The source file which I gave is part of a paper which I am going to submit to a scientific journal and their require nicely aligned captions.

Comment: the `caption` and `subcaption` packages are not compatible with revtex` package. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135718/caption-automatically-centered-in-a-revtex-document.

Comment: Dear Zanko, How should I rewrite my source file?

Comment: If you are submitting to a journal using revtex then, as author, you should not restyle the document, the whole point of a publisher class like revtex is to remove choice from the author and enforce the publication style.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[...]
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}   
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false,justification=justified}  
[...]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formatting (line-centered caption) arises from the `revtex4` document class.  Here, I create my own caption justification option with `\DeclareCaptionJustification{myjust}{\fulljustify}`.

I defined `\fulljustify` by starting with the `caption` package definition of `\centerlast` and modifying it to get rid of the centered last line.

The option `justification=justified`, which would normally work in other document classes, is actually a null option, adding zero additional code, thus assuming the document class default is fully justified (which it is not for `revtex4`).

```
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\documentclass[aps,prl]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{epstopdf}   % this graphic package converts eps to pdf for easier usage of eps files
\usepackage{lpic}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\lstset{mathescape=true}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right|}
\newcommand{\is}[1]{{\color{blue} #1}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{myjust}{\fulljustify}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\fulljustify{%
  \let\\\@centercr
  \leftskip\z@%
  \rightskip\z@%
  \parfillskip\z@\@plus 1fill\relax%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textbf{Corresponding author information}\\
Ad van der Ven, email: a.vanderven@pwo.ru.nl
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.50\textwidth}
{\bf Figure}
  \caption{Based on the observed data sets}
  \label{fig:RegressionFixedObservedN4451}
\end{subfigure}
\captionsetup{justification=myjust,singlelinecheck=false}
\caption{Regression plot for the fixed condition of the ACT (N = 445). The
 x-axis represents the natural logarithm of the absolute value of the minimum
 residual score belonging to the sequence of 14 consecutive bars with the
 smallest MSE. The y-axis represents the smallest MSE. The top line is the
 line $y = 2x + \ln{10}$. The bottom line is the line $y = 2x-\ln{10}$. The
 line exactly in between is the line $y=2x$.}
\label{fig:observedfixedcondion}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why the +/- fil skips in left and rightskip? the default text justification simply uses 0pt  there?

Comment: Dear Steven B. Segletes, you in fact answered my question. Thank you very, very much for your answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As I explained, I tweaked what was in the `caption` package.  It's black magic to me.

Comment: I think they could be `\z@` with no difference in the output unless there is an fil glue added within the caption (the behaviour of `\hspace{0pt plus 1fil}`  in the presence of those settings is well defined but probably surprising:-)

Comment: testing my suggestions?, you show such little faith!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would help if I tested it properly.  You are correct.