# How can I apply bold-face and left alignment to all figure and table captions?

Tags: captions, ieeeaccess

I am trying to prepare a paper for IEEE Open Access that uses `\documentclass{ieeeccess}` ; its template (https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/LaTeX.zip).

When I look into their published papers Figure and Table captions are bold and left-aligned, like:

[image]

[image]

I just wanted to apply textbf{} to all figure and table captions but while keeping the original style such as Figure text color is blue.

cleaned code example:

```tex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}
\author{\uppercase{First A. Author}\authorrefmark{1}, \IEEEmembership{Fellow, IEEE},
\uppercase{Second B. Author\authorrefmark{2}, and Third C. Author,
Jr}.\authorrefmark{3},
\IEEEmembership{Member, IEEE}}

\begin{abstract}
These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for ...
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Enter key words or phrases in alphabetical
order, separated by commas. For a list of suggested keywords, send a blank
e-mail to keywords@ieee.org or visit \underline
{http://www.ieee.org/organizations/pubs/ani\_prod/keywrd98.txt}
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.png}
  \caption{Dummy figure.}
  \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\EOD
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Here I can easily do `\caption{\textbf{Dummy figure.}}` , but have many figures that if possible I want to do this through `captionsetup` package.

---

Is it possible to apply `\textbf{}` for all the caption an tables labels and left-align them, while keeping their original font-style and color unchanged?

Related: [Align Caption to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275141/127048)

Comment: If you attend to publish article in IEEE journal why you like to change their desired document settings defined by `ieeeacces` document class? Dont doing this!

Comment: Sorry for the misguide, in the template `\textbf{}` was embedded in the label to make caption bold.
I was looking for a solution to apply this globally without writing `\textbf` inside all the labels.

Comment: Note that the template they provided conflicts from the published papers. One of the table (in their template) exceeds the column width, where I am not sure it it acceptable or not. Also in the references, templated underlines the URL but neither publish paper does that. I just wanted to make their job easier , but I get lost to figure it out what is right or wrong

Comment: If IEEE is changing their caption format, they are doing it automatically by redefining `\caption`.  They don't need and will not appreciate your help.

Comment: @John Kormylo
 Ah I am not chaning their `\caption` format. In the templated it is used as `\caption{\textbf{MY CAPTION}}` so muanually writes should add `\textbf{}` one by one into to ALL Tables and Figures.   Instead I was looking for a global decleration to handle this at least for my draft work

Comment: If you are only doing it for drafts, you can use the caption package to customize the caption any way you want.  Just remember to remove it before submitting.  You might also check to see if there is a newer template available for authors.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! I // I double checked their site (https://ieeeaccess.ieee.org/guide-for-authors/preparing-your-article/) there is only one LaTeX template link, seems like they did not updated it with a newer one :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: replaced `subcaption` with `caption` according to Mico's comment.

I believe this blog contains all the answers your are looking for:

https://latex-tutorial.com/caption-customization-latex/

Most importantly this is the part you want to focus on:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom}
{%
    \textbf{#1#2}\textit{\small #3}
}
\captionsetup{format=custom}
```

### Explanation:

The package `caption` enables the use of `captionsetup` that will apply to all captions. By declaring a new `format` named `custom`, the author set argument 1 and 2 (`#1 , #2`) to bold and `#3` to italic.

From the example:

1. `#1` is the figurename, Figure in English
2. `#2` is the refcount.
3. `#3` is the content of the caption itself.

You can play around or read the entire blog to have a better understanding.

Comment: +1. The `subcaption` package loads `caption.sty` automatically. Unless one needs to create `subfigure` and `subtable` environments, your sample code could be streamlined by loading the `caption` package directly, without the detour via `subcaption`.

Comment: thank you, I have edited the answer.