# Beamer: left-aligned caption of centered figure

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

I am doing which should be a simple task, but I cannot fathom why it does not work...
I just want a simple caption of a figure I centered, aligned to the left of the figure, right down its lower left corner.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usepackage[labelformat=empty,
    font=scriptsize,
    skip=0pt,
    justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{my caption here}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: fig1]

How can I have the caption right below the bottom left corner of my image? And why does the code above not work?

Please note the solution should also work within a \figure environment to add captions to tikzpictures...

Thanks!

**EDIT:
I TRIED justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false AS SUGGESTED [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/how-can-i-left-align-a-caption), BUT STILL NO SUCCESS...**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[labelformat=empty,font=scriptsize,skip=0pt,
justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{my caption here}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: b]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use package `threeparttable` to restrict the caption width to the width of the image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,font=scriptsize,skip=0pt,
justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
      %\centering% not needed, because default
      \begin{measuredfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{my caption here}
      \end{measuredfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: caption below image restricted to image width]

Usually you do not need explicit `center` or `\centering`, because `beamer` centers the figure by default (see the result in the image above). Instead, if you want left aligned or right aligned figures you have to add `\raggedright` or `\raggedleft` just after `\begin{figure}`. Nevertheless, you can activate the commented `\centering`.

Comment: This is it! Isn't the use of "measuredfigure" and  "figure" redundant though? Only with "measuredfigure" I get the same result

Comment: @DaniCee Without `figure` the image wouldn't be centered by default. So you would need an additional environment to center it.

Comment: what about without "figure" but with "centering"?

Comment: @DaniCee `\centering` would center the whole frame not only the picture. `center` could be used, but why not using `figure`? `center` would be physical markup, `figure` is semantic markup. Semantic markup should be preferred, because you can change all figures at once in the preamble of the document. It would make more sense to redefine `figure` to be a centered `measuredfigure` than to put all `measuredfigure` into a `center`-environment. But I do not recommend to do so, because if you would have a very small image, a `measuredfigure` could be very ugly.

Comment: for the win: How would you align the caption to the right side instead? I tried with \raggedleft before the caption, but nothing happened...

Comment: @DaniCee `justification=raggedleft` instead of `justification=raggedright`.

Comment: oh right, but I mean locally; I want all my captions on the left, except one I want on the right

Comment: You can set the option local to the `figure` environment using `\captionsetup` or for all `measuredfigure` environments using the optional argument of `\captionsetup` in the document preamble. See the `caption` manual for more information on how to configure it locally or globally.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the image and its caption in an additional `minipage` could be a solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But a single line caption would be centered without using package `caption`. AFAIK the OP want it left aligned with the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think, using a floating object like the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` or `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` is in conflict of the needs of a presentation.  A floating object is something, which LaTeX may move around to get the best possible word, line and page wrapping.  Therefore it may move the image to the end of the chapter.  In a presentation, you don't want to jump forth and back between your slides.  You normally want a continuous flow from one slide to the next.

Having said that, you don't want to use a floating object in beamer, at least not in the presentation forms.

Having said that, you don't want to use `\caption`-like commands, as you don't have a `figure`-environment.

The solution in your case: just remove the `\caption`-command (and even the `caption`-package) and it works.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}\\
    my caption here
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand why the use of captions is not recommended in Beamer... this is the first time I read something like this.

Comment: The problem is I have way more complicated layouts than that in the MWE, so in those cases what should I do to replace the captions?? put the figure in a tikzpicture node and the caption as text in another node? that sounds really overly complicating things...

Comment: I don't think floats are the problem here. I can't try right now but: have you tried removing the grouping braces around the \usepackage command? \mode<presentation> does not take arguments afaik

Comment: Right, it's the singlelinecheck=false argument what causes it... But without it the caption is centered below the image; I'd like the caption to be aligned left with the image... I am editing to reflect this

Comment: `figure` and `table` in `beamer` are not floating. They are placed where they are used. See section 12.6 in the beamer user manual.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: `\caption` is a command, that belongs to floats.  Therefore my comments on floating objects used in presentations.  But the OP didn't use the `figure`-environment in his MWE.

Comment: @Jan `\caption` in `figure` of `beamer` does not belong to floats, because `figure` does not float. `beamer` does not provide floating objects at all.

Comment: @Jan In beamer you can just as well use `figure`, as it is redefinded to do basically not much more then centering ...

Comment: @Jan: BTW: You answer does not left align the *caption* below the centered image.