# How can I left align a caption for a centered table?

Tags: tables, captions

I want to left-align the caption of a table.

I read [How can I left-align a caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/how-can-i-left-align-a-caption) and the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption) without luck.

This code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
    \caption{System specifications}
    \label{tab:specs}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
         Processor & Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @2.70GHz 2.90 GHz \\
         Installed RAM & 8.00 GB (7.89 GB usable)
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Creates this:

[image]

I want the caption to be justified with the left border of the table itself and not the paragraph:

[image]

(NB: picture above is edited in MS paint...)

Comment: With use of threeparttable. Please extend your code snišped to complete small document (MWE) that we can more easy show how.

Comment: The caption always fills the available width (with white space).  Another solution is to reduce the width using a minipage (once you know how wide the tabular is).

Comment: Zarko, Like this? Sorry if I am mistaken - I am new to tex.stackexchange.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, how can I obtain the width of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the addition of `@{}` to each side of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
         Processor & Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @2.70GHz 2.90 GHz \\
         Installed RAM & 8.00 GB (7.89 GB usable)
    \end{tabular}}%
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\wd0}
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=justified}
    \caption{System specifications}
    \label{tab:specs}
    \usebox0
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Aha! Thanks! So the intuition is that you create a box with the tabular inside. This box is then referred to inside the centered minipage (relative to the paragraph), which allows the justification to refer to the end of the box instead of the paragraph?

Comment: You can also use \settowidth or \widthof (calc package), but internally they are using saveboxes.  This way you only have to format the box once.  Note: one should only use box registers 0-9 inside groups (environments).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you (a) keep loading the `caption` package and (b) employ a `threeparttable` environment to encase both the `\caption` directive and the `tabular` environment. It measures the width of the `tabular` environment and limits the width of the caption string to that width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % see https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, justification=raggedright}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{System specifications}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
         Processor & Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @2.70\,GHz 2.90\,GHz \\
         Installed RAM & 8.00 GB (7.89 GB usable)
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```